Is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ISO available with valid bootloader?
When I try to use Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS installation media (AMD64, Desktop) the bootloaderis no longer valid and prevents use with Secure Boot. Is any ISO for version 20.04 LTS Desktop for AMD64 available with a valid certificate?
N.B. Following the link from @guiverc, below, leads to the same issue. Today, 2024.12.23, after downloading ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso, and using Rufus to try to make a boot USB, the following was shown:

Having a USB with Ubuntu Live is a convenience, useful for repairs, drive backup and resizing, etc. Yes, one could disable Secure Boot, boot from USB, and re-enable Secure boot, a nuisance and potential security risk if it is not enabled again. A later version of Ubuntu could be used -- but with different kernel, desktop and other changes. It would be better to have the latest version of 20.04 LTS with a valid certificate.
BTW, has the bootloader certificate expired and not been renewed? Has the issuing authority reason to believe it's been abused? Are there security issues with 20.04 LTS that forced Ubuntu to revoke the certificate? Or is there another reason for that issue?
Addendum
Microsoft has apparently revoked the Ubuntu shim in a Windows update. Thanks to Thomas Ward and Ubuntu team for explanation!

When a key is revoked, new media is created and released; eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ says "Unlike previous point releases, 20.04.6 is a refresh of the amd64 installer media after recent key revocations, re-enabling their usage on Secure Boot enabled systems."  A total of 7 Desktop/Server ISOs have been released just for amd64 and the 20.04 release; where you specify just release details (no clues as to which 20.04 media you're referring to, as YES some were released with what are now revoked keys)

Note that the reason for revocation isn't going to always be stated. So redo your install media with 20.04.6 media not 20.04 old media

@ThomasWard, yes, it was 20.04.6 that has the issue of revoked bootloader. Though an explanation would be nice to satisfy my curiosity, more important would be to have any version of 20.04.x LTS with valid bootloader.


Note: This issue only happens when you are using Windows / Rufus / etc. and updated signing keys applied by Windows Update (since August 2024) on a system that ONLY has Windows on it. Windows is supposed to not overwrite or change these keys when have other OSes but Windows on it, but there is no guarantee it won't mess with the accepted keys anyways.

I reached out to the Release Team and got, essentially the reply of the following (paraphrased):

The Release Team is aware that the latest round of Microsoft patching resulted in changes to MOK and shim on Windows-only machines.
The key in 20.04.6 media is not actually revoked/expired by us, but Microsoft expired it in the latest round of updates.
Due to the age of 20.04, we are not producing new ISOs for that release (especially since it reaches End of Standard Support in 2025).
Long term, if Microsoft is going to push out revocations through MS Update, this may not be a solution, but we'll have to revisit that in the future.

There is also a note here that Microsoft pushed out an update that revokes all shim versions 15.7 or earlier, hence why 20.04.6 fails to validate.  This is documented on the Ubuntu Discourse:

On 20th August 2024, Windows released a software patch that revoked
shims older than 15.8. The shim is an upstream component consumed by
multiple Linux distros, including Ubuntu.
Which Ubuntu users are affected

Any user intending to install any version of Ubuntu on hardware that currently runs Windows, with secure boot enabled, and the relevant
update installed.
Existing dual-boot setups of any Ubuntu release except for 24.04 LTS, alongside Windows, that has secure boot enabled and has received
the relevant Windows update.

Dedicated Ubuntu machines are unaffected.
How this affects Ubuntu users
As a result of this update, any Ubuntu released media that uses a shim
older than 15.8 can no longer be directly installed on machines that
have applied this Windows update without disabling secure boot first
in the BIOS. This may include fresh systems that have had Windows
pre-installed or existing dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu systems older
than Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Whilst Ubuntu 24.04 LTS already includes the 15.8 shim when installed,
the current release ISOs use shim 15.7 to perform the installation.
Therefore, users will still require updated installation media to
resolve this issue for fresh installs of 24.04 on machines that have
received the Windows update.
When can you expect a fix?
Mitigating the impact of this change requires shipping Ubuntu releases
with updated shim 15.8. This effort is underway, and Canonical will
make available updated install media (ISOs) for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
(Noble Numbat) as part of the .1 release on August 29th. The upcoming
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS release will also include the same updates.
This will ensure that both Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and 22.04 LTS will be
installable on systems affected by the Windows update.
How to mitigate this change on existing Ubuntu installations
For existing Ubuntu installations that are experiencing issues it is
possible to use the following workarounds before we release the new
ISOs:
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and above:

Disable secure boot in the device BIOS settings.
[optional] Install the system, if you don't yet have an install.
Boot into Ubuntu and then, depending on release version:

24.04: You are good to go, the installed system is fine as the installed system has the 15.8 shim.
20.04/22.04: Prior to
August 29th the patch is available in the proposed pocket. After
August 29th the patch will become generally available and users will
simply need to update their system to upgrade to the new shim using
the following command: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade shim-signed.


Boot Ubuntu a second time (with secure boot still disabled), this will cause the shim to reset the SBAT.
Reboot into the BIOS and re-enable secure boot.


If you absolutely must use 20.04.6, you should disable secure boot, update Ubuntu, install the updated shim versions, etc., and then enable secure boot and enroll any corresponding keys.
Note that I have tested the 20.04.6 ISO on VM environments that're with updated UEFI / Secure Boot firmware available, but also on desktops that dual-boot Windows or don't have Windows installed, and the ISO doesn't show as revoked when booted to, so you might be seeing a Windows/Rufus error that is not accurate to how the media will actually boot on systems not running Windows.

Thank you for the full explanation! The key is, "The key in 20.04.6 media is not actually revoked/expired by us, but Microsoft expired it in the latest round of updates." That I can understand, and work around.

@DrMoishePippik yeah they expired shim-signed versions earlier than 15.8.  15.8 has CVEs and security patches, but usually most places revoke to latest-minus-one, whereas MS did this with an extra expiration to latest-only.  Which in turn is why Rufus and Windows state this.

W.r.t Windows does not overrite or change these keys when have other OSes but Windows on it there might be some cases where that doesn't work. I had a PC with secure boot enabled which dual boots Windows 11 and AlmaLinux 8.10, with GRUB and GRUB and Linux on a different disk to Windows. A Windows 11 update did revoke a key which prevented an older live ISO from booting from USB media. I'm not sure if the Microsoft detection for other OSes only looks on the disk on which Windows is installed.

@ChesterGillon I'm simply relaying what was told to me by the Release Team.  Windows likes to monopolize systems which is why systems I have either have Windows only (because needed like a gaming desktop), or are VMs inside of Linux systems (and can't mess with the secure boot on the host system)
